# required type [org.quartz.Trigger] for property 'triggers[0]'

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I am using spring4.0，quartz2.2.1.I get exception when I try to start my server:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.util.ArrayList] to required type [org.quartz.Trigger] for property 'triggers[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:267)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:128)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertToTypedArray(TypeConverterDelegate.java:441)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:198)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:458)
```

this is my xml

```
 <!-- 定义调用方法 -->
    <bean id="activityReportTask" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetObject">
            <ref bean="activityJob"/>
        </property>
        <property name="targetMethod">
            <value>excuteActivityJob</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- 定义触发器 -->
    <bean id="activityReportTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetail">
            <ref bean="activityReportTask"/>
        </property>
        <property name="cronExpression">
            <value>0 0/1 * * * ?</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- 加载定时器工厂 -->
    <bean id="ziwowScheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <list>
                    <ref bean="activityReportTrigger"/>
                </list>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

it means SchedulerFactoryBean.triggers must be type of org.quartz.Trigger,but CronTriggerFactoryBean is not extend from Trigger.

anyone helps

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your schedulerFactoryBean definition as below.

```
<bean id="ziwowScheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
   <property name="triggers">
          <list>
               <ref bean="activityReportTrigger"/>
            </list>
   </property>
```

You have added multiple list on property triggers.

Answer (score 0):

just add quartz dependency as below

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```